# How to add PATH variable to Linux App Service Plan

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I deployed Python Azure Function that runs on Linux App Service Plan. In Python code, I call BCP command ultility to import data to MSSQL. But the problem is BCP not in the PATH environment variable so it gave me an error:

```
-bash: bcp command not found.
```

I use Kudu(root privilege) to connect to App Service Plan to register the PATH and call successfully from terminal but somehow Python cannot call it though Subprocess.
So, how do I register the PATH variable to Azure app Service plan and Python can call it throught SubProcess?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the [command-line tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-migrate-bcp?view=sql-server-ver15#install-the-sql-server-command-line-tools).

To make sqlcmd/bcp accessible from the bash shell for interactive/non-login sessions, modify the PATH in the **~/.bashrc** file